# Adding Email Channel to Microsoft Bot Framework Shows Timeout errors

Tags: azure, botframework, azure-bot-service

I have a Chat Bot and already have a Slack channel and works fine.
When I try to Save an Email I am getting the following error:
[image]

Error:

```
Unable to save. The Operation did not complete within the specified timeout.
```

Based on the documentations I am using an O365 email

Comment: Just this bot service can not configure Email channel? Do you try to configure Email channel for your other bot service with same email credentials?

Comment: I only have this one Bot so far.

Comment: You can try to create a [support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) to report it.

Comment: We are addressing this issue on our [GitHub](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/4615)